# sqoop export to Teradata gives com.teradata.connector.common.exception.ConnectorException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding

Tags: hdfs, teradata, sqoop, sqoop2

I am trying to export data from HDFS to Teradata using sqoop. I have created a table in Teradata and tried to import a sample text file with some sample data. Here is my sqoop export command

sqoop export --connect jdbc:teradata://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/Database=XXXXXXX,CHARSET=UTF8 \
--username User_name  \
--password pwd \
--export-dir /user/User/test_td_export/ \
--table HDP_TD_EXPORT_TEST \
--input-fields-terminated-by ',' \
--input-escaped-by '\' \
--input-enclosed-by '\"' \
--input-optionally-enclosed-by '\"' \
--mapreduce-job-name td_export_test

I am able to do a sqoop eval to the same table to get the count successfully but while exporting data, I am getting the exception.

19/01/04 20:48:26 ERROR tool.ExportTool: Encountered IOException running export job:
com.teradata.connector.common.exception.ConnectorException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding

This is the first time I have tried to export to teradata. I have exported data to Oracle and didn't see any such issues. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found that usage of --input-escaped-by \ \ is causing the above exception as it is adding the escape characters while exporting. I have removed that parameter and the export job worked as expected.